# Why are all the tabs except MBeans disabled in JConsole? (when using "Remote Process" connection)

Tags: monitoring, java, jmx

I'm trying to connect to JConsole on a server running:
java version "1.6.0_0"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.4.1) (6b14-1.4.1-0ubuntu12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b08, mixed mode)

When I connect using the "Local Process" method, all the tabs are enabled -- when I connect via the "Remote Process" method, it connects just fine, but the only tab that is enabled is the MBeans tab.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the local process method will connect you to the JVM's [platform MBeanServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getPlatformMBeanServer%28%29), which is where all the management MXBeans are registered that supply all the data for those other tabs. However, when you connect remotely (and this varies by application/application server), may applications tend to spin up one or more of their own MBeanServers which do not have the management MXBeans registered. Consequently, JConsole cannot render those tabs because it does not see the MXBeans required to do so.

If you see a bunch of application server specific MBeans in JConsole when you connect remotely  (like jboss, or weblogic) then that's what's going on.

Comment: Can the platform mbean server be accessed instead of the application server one(s)?